# MongoDB starting with status error on macOS

Tags: mongodb, macos, runtime-error

I'm using homebrew to initialize mongodb as it follows:

`brew services start mongodb-community@5.0`

It starts successfully

> ==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)

However, when I type `mongo`to run mongodb, I keep getting connection refused:

> MongoDB shell version v5.0.2
> connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
> Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
> connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
> @(connect):2:6
> exception: connect failed
> exiting with code 1

So I typed `brew services list` to check if the mongoDB is up, and it seems it started with an error status:

| Name | Status | User | Plist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mongodb-community | error | guilhermemendes | /opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community/... |

Comment: What do you see when you issue the command `ps -ef | grep mongod`?

Comment: It seems the field Plist is the most interesting, but it is also truncated.  Can you determine the full path of the file `mongod`?  It seems it is in the path `/opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community/...` but the path is not complete...

Comment: I'm sorry, the path is ```/opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist```

Comment: That's the response when I grep the mongod:  ```501 31900 31873   0 10:15PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep mongod```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but unfortunately this is not the reference to the mongod.  If you can find out what the service command is to run you can run it manually and get output of an error why it won't start.  There should be a mongod.conf file somewhere that will have configuration for starting including data file paths, port numbers, and IP Bindings.  With this it can help diagnose the problem

Comment: Once you find where the file `mongod` is located, and where the file `mongod.conf` is located you can issue the command `mongod -f <configuration file path>` and see the error output.  The config file will have a directory where datafiles are listed.  If you are running this command under your own account you will need to be granted permissions to this directory.  For testing it might make sense to create a directory for which you have write permissions and edit the config file to set the data file path to this directory you have write access to then issue `mongod -f <config file path>`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @barrypicker . I'm gonna try to find the mongod.conf path

Comment: I found the path /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb, but there is no mongod.conf file inside it, only mongod.lock

Answer (score 0):

check the following.

1. if you are using M1 based MacOS then install mongo db (and brew) with `Rosetta`.
2. check the IP binding on mongo config
   (`/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` or `/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf`)
3. verify the connection string URI format - [Mongo docs - connection-string-uri-format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-uri-format)

Comment: That is my mongod.conf: ```systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1```.   In which configuration should I include the URI connection?

Comment: you don't have to include the connection string in any of your configuration files. 
try to use the connection string along with the mongo command. Refer to this page for more options - https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/program/mongo/#syntax

Also, verify your mongo is running on your system `lsof -i :27017`